# Trying to get cmake add_compile_options to work

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying a very simple example with cmake to use the `add_compile_options` directive

CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_compile_options(-Wall)
MESSAGE("COMPILE OPTIONS ${COMPILE_OPTIONS}")
add_executable(test main.cpp)
```

where main.cpp is some (empty) main function. I do

```
rm -r CMakeFiles/ cmake_install.cmake Makefile test CMakeCache.txt
cmake CMakeLists.txt
make VERBOSE=1
```

cmake output like:

```
<snip>
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
<snip>
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
COMPILE OPTIONS 
<snip>
-- Build files have been written to: /a_directory/test
```

Note the line `COMPILE_OPTIONS` shows an empty variable which I understand the `add_compile_options` directive should set. make returns

```
<snip>
[100%] Linking CXX executable test
/a_path/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/test.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++    -L/a/libdir -L/another/libdir -rdynamic CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.o  -o test 
<snip>
```

and there is no `-Wall`

what am I doing wrong? Nb: `cmake version 3.15.3`

Comment: The shown output of `make VERBOSE=1`  describes the **linkage**, which produces executable file from the object file (`main.o`). As you could guess from the command's name, `add_compile_options` adds options for use in the **compilation** step, when source file (`main.cpp` in your case) is compiled into the object file. That is, you need to search `-Wall` in the other part of `make` output. BTW, it is always preferred to use **out-of-source** builds with CMake: `mkdir build`, `cd build`, `cmake ..`. In that case removing build arifacts is as simple as `rm -rf *` from the build directory.

Comment: "Note the line `COMPILE_OPTIONS` shows an empty variable which I understand the `add_compile_options` directive should set" - No, your understanding id wrong. As you can see from the documentation, [add_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html), sets a directory **property** named `COMPILE_OPTION`. Value of that property could be extracted by using `get_directory_property` or `get_property` command.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - will have a look

Comment: So it looks like I was using `add_compile_options` rather than `add_link_options`, hence the mistake. Thanks to @Tsyvarev